# $and in $match MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, match

I am trying to use the following query in MongoDB but it is not running.

```
db.chicago.aggregate([{$match: {$and: [ {PERMIT_TYPE: "PERMIT - ELEVATOR 
EQUIPMENT"}, {AMOUNT_PAID:{$gt:50000, $lt:75000}}]}},{$group: 
{_id:"$PERMIT_TYPE", counts: {$sum: 1}}},{$sort:{"counts": 1}}])
```

There is no error message displayed when I output this query. It would only displayed a new line.

Thank you in advance for your help and guidance.

Comment: db.chicago.find({"PERMIT_TYPE": "PERMIT - ELEVATOR EQUIPMENT ", "AMOUNT_PAID":{$gt:50000, $lt:75000}}}) What o/p do you get?

Comment: @Astro I get the following output: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell):1:101